# Проверка на то что пользователь уже существует Symfony

Tags: php, symfony2

Здравствуйте, сделал регистрацию и авторизацию на симфони 2 по этому туториалу: https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html

Но при регистрации симфони не проверяет существует ли пользователь с таким же email. Подскажите пожалуйста новичку как это можно реальзовать ? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
$userRepository = $em->getRepository(\AppBundle\Entity\User::class);
$userExist = (bool)$userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $user->getEmail()]);

if ($userExist) {
    // действия, если пользователь с таким email уже зарегистрирован
}
```